# Entity Framework - Same field and column name in base and derived classes

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4.3 and am adding Audit fields to my classes and tables. I have a service layer which is getting the credentials of the client applications by using the OperationContext, so I am passing that information to my tables through EF mappings. An example of this would be:

```
class A 
{
   string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}

class B  : A 
{

}
```

I am using the fluent interface to provide my POCO to table mappings -- when I map the `CreatedByUser` column in the base and derived class, the derived class mappings do not take effect and the information is not passed to the database.

I have gotten around this by creating fields in my base class for the derived classes to use that are just pass-throughs of the audit columns but this is messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try making class A abstract, I think that will give you the effect you are looking for(add the columns from class A to all class/tables that inherit it)

Comment: imho that will lead to a TPH storage (or a non materialization of class A) that is one table for all the derived types. I'm not sure that is the searched behaviour. If not, I'm not sure EF allows to "duplicate" a column at database/storage/persistence level.

Comment: @tschmit007 He says "am adding Audit fields to my classes and tables".  This will do just that, add the fields from class A to all of the derived tables.

Comment: Let me provide a little more info -- I am using TPT rather than TPH, meaning I have tables for both Class A and B (mentioned in my first post). I can try making the base class (A) abstract, but I'm not sure what, if anything, that will do. I definitely want to stick with TPT and stay away from TPC and TPH.

Comment: Reading through this proposed answer it sounds like it is a suggestion to use TPC (table per concrete-class). I definitely don't want to go with that methodology, but I will go ahead and try the abstract change to see what it does.

Comment: @JerryHikel Yes, this will quite literally add the fields from class A to class B.  Meaning there will be no class A table, and instead each derived class like B, will have those columns.  So I guess you'll need to be more verbose about the problem your having, it's not clear what you are seeing as far as "the derived class mappings do not take effect".

Comment: That would change my structure to be TPC -- table per concrete class -- I am not using that methodology, I am using TPT.